# Difference between timestamps as days

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, data-science

I am trying to create a column with the difference between two timestamps. The difference should be represented as days.

```
data = {'date1':['2020-12-01 00:00:00', '2020-12-09 00:00:00']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])

benchmark=pd.Timestamp('2020-12-11 00:00:00')
benchmark-df['date1']
```

Output:

```
0   10 days
1    2 days
Name: date1, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

The above gives the difference as a Timedelta, from which the days can be extracted - is there a shorter and efficient way to get the days as an int other than iterating over each row to extract the days attribute?

Comment: `(benchmark-df['date1']  ).dt.days   `?